# Preposition with phrase passed away

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Is "My grandmother passed away from cancer last night" grammatically correct and acceptable?

Comment: Welcome. You may be interested in visiting our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. Do you have any particular concerns about it? Note that some death verbs take _from,_ some take _of,_ and some take either. For example, you can “die of cancer” or “die from cancer,” although I think most people would prefer the first. In contrast, you wouldn't normally say “passed away of cancer.”

Comment: I probably wouldn't use "passed away" with a *from* clause.  I'd be likely to say just, "My grandmother passed away last night." and then either tack on an additional sentence with, "She had cancer." or else change to *died*:  "My grandmother died of cancer last night."

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatical, but no, it is not acceptable.

The phrase *passed away* is a euphemism for 'died' and is used in a formal sentence. It is not appropriate to include the cause of death with *passed away*, although the time and place of death may be.

> "My grandmother passed away <strike>from cancer</strike> last night. She had cancer."

or

> "My grandmother died from (/of) cancer last night."

Comment: Hey, good answer ;-) +1